# jQuery selector for checkbox inside <span> with CSS class name

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

I am trying to setup a single checkbox that will toggle on/off all the checkboxes in an ASP.NET GridView. I am looking to do all of this client-side. No need to PostBack. I figured I could use jQuery as it is already included in the project (jQuery v1.11).

I thought I would assign a unique style to the checkboxes and use jQuery to select the checkbox via the css class however it turns out that ASP.NET is rendering the checkbox element inside a span and is assigning the unique CSS style to the `<span>` rather than the checkbox element itself.

```
<span class="MyUniqueStyleName">
  <input type="checkbox" .... >
</span>
```

What sort of jQuery selector is used to access the actual checkbox? I tried the following without any luck.

```
$('span.MyUniqueStyleName input')
```

Here is the jQuery I am using to toggle all the checkboxes. It is placed right after the GridView. The *toggle* checkbox has the class `chkToggleAll`.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('input.chkToggleAll').click(function () {
        $('span.MyUniqueStyleName input').each(function () {
          $(this).attr('checked', $('input.chkToggleAll').attr('checked'));
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Your selector seems to be fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jLsx0y58/1/ . Are you running it before the HTML has rendered, by any chance? Note the `$(function() {` callback function wrapped round the code in that JSFiddle - it's a shortened form of "document.ready" which ensures the code doesn't run until the page has fully rendered and the HTML being targeted actually exists in the DOM.

Comment: I have placed the script itself right after the rendering of the GridView. I have updated the question with the script I am using.

Comment: `input.chkToggleAll` should be `span.chkToggleAll` like it is later in the code. I think it's just a typo.

Comment: @ADyson - The master toggle checkbox is not rendered from an ASP.NET control so it is just a standard checkbox element `<input type="checkbox" class="chkToggleAll">`

Comment: In that case it's simply the opposite problem, surely? `$('span.chkToggleAll input')` in the above snippet should be `$('input.chkToggleAll')`?

Comment: I have corrected that in the sample code. Still does not toggle the checkboxes though. I know `$('input.chkToggleAll')` is selecting properly because I throw up an `alert()` when it is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there apart from a couple of niggles. This version corrects a few problems and makes the code slightly more efficient.

The main things to note are

1) the use of .prop() instead of .attr(). This is crucial and is the main reason your code doesn't work. Check the jquery docs at http://api.jquery.com/prop/ to understand why this is the correct method to use.

2) Handling the "change" instead of "click" event on the checkbox  (it's mainly by convention, click will work too)

3) You don't need the .each loop, because when using .prop (or .attr for that matter) it applies the change to all the selected elements automatically - this is noted in the documentation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chkToggleAll').change(function() {
    var checked = $('.chkToggleAll').prop('checked');
    $('span.MyUniqueStyleName input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkToggleAll" />Toggle All
<span class="MyUniqueStyleName">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1"/>1
</span>
<span class="MyUniqueStyleName">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox2"/>2
</span>
<span class="MyUniqueStyleName">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox3"/>3
</span>
<span class="MyUniqueStyleName">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox4"/>4
</span>
```

Comment: Excellent and well explained answer! Thanks for the info and link on `props` vs `attr`. Also, the explanation of why a loop is not needed. One question .. why the double quotes around checked instead of single quotes in `.prop("checked", checked);`? I remain confused as to when to use double quotes `"` and when to use single quotes `'` in Javascript.

Comment: @webworm No problem. The quote marks are largely interchangeable. It can be useful to use one or the other occasionally if you want to contain the opposite thing within a string. e.g. if you write a string `var message = "I'm happy today"`, you wouldn't be able to put that in single quotes because of the apostrophe. Likewise if you wrote `var message = 'ADyson is "happy" today'` it wouldn't work in double quotes. Where there's no issue like that, it doesn't really matter which you choose.

Comment: @webworm In fact, looking back the question, the CSS selector `span.MyUniqueStyleName input[type="checkbox"]'` is a perfect example of when this interchangeability can be useful. If all JS strings had to be in double quotes, like in, say C#, then you'd have an unpleasant time putting in backslashes all over the place to keep escaping the quote characters within the string.